# EDM mapping error

Tags: c#

I inserted previoulsy created *.msl, *.ssdl and *.csdl files into my new project and during compile I got error in mapping part:

```
  <AssociationSetMapping Name="FK_application_financial_risk_id" TypeName="Repository.FK_application_financial_risk_id" StoreEntitySet="application">
    <EndProperty Name="application_financial_risk">
      <ScalarProperty Name="risk_id" ColumnName="High_Financial_Risk_id" />
    </EndProperty>
    <EndProperty Name="application">
      <ScalarProperty Name="application_id" ColumnName="application_id" />
    </EndProperty>
    <Condition ColumnName="High_Financial_Risk_id" IsNull="false" />
  </AssociationSetMapping>
```

> Error 4   Error 3012: Problem in mapping fragments starting at lines
>   4705, 5439, 5439, 5439, 5456, 5465, 5474, 5483:Data loss is possible
>   in
>   FK_application_financial_risk_id.application_financial_risk.risk_id.
>   An Entity with Key (PK) will not round-trip when:   (Entity.risk_id =
>   'True' AND Entity.application_financial_risk.risk_id = 'False' AND PK
>   plays Role 'application' in AssociationSet
>   'FK_application_financial_risk_id')   5440    11  Tracker

My question is if If I can change something in above code to remove the error? I tried comment this part but it doesn't help.